# Detect DNS redirection from python

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping, python-requests

I am writing a small web scraping application with Python.  The app scrapes data from a list of websites that often redirect to a new site.  Sometimes the website that I am directed to does not exist.  When that happens on my local machine, my ISP redirects me to another site (using `<meta http-equiv="refresh">`):

```
In [1]: import requests
In [2]: r = requests.get('http://www.asdflksdjk2.com')

In [3]: r.status_code
Out[3]: 200

In [4]: r.url
Out[4]: u'http://www.asdflksdjk2.com'

In [5]: r.text
Out[5]: u'<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" 
content="0;url=http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL=http://www.asdflksdjk2.com/"/>
</head><body><script>
window.location="http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL="+escape(window.location)+"&r="+escape(document.referrer);
</script></body></html>'
```

When I run the same code on a vps hosted by digitalocean and I get something different:

```
In [1]: import requests
In [2]: r = requests.get('http://www.asdflksdjk2.com')

In [3]: r.status_code
Out[3]: 200

In [4]: r.url
Out[4]: u'http://gen.xyz/success#asdflksdjk2.xyz'
```

This time I am redirected away from the page to this `gen.xyz` site:

```
In [5]: for hist in r.history:
            print hist.url, hist.status_code
Out[5]: 
http://www.asdflksdjk2.com 302
http://gen.xyz/availability-checker.php?src=www.asdflksdjk2 302
```

Is there a portable method of detecting pages that no longer exist?